LoRA in PEFT can't reduce too much GPU memory consumption as we expected
I try to use lora to finetune a VIT for image classification:

I download the vit-base-patch16-224-in21k model from huggingface
I use the peft in huggingface to implement lora with ViT

Code could run successfully but it could not reduce the GPU memory consumption to even half of the original amount.
To show how much GPU memory consumption could be reduced by lora, I separately run "linear-probing, full-finetune (tune all the parameters), lora" to fine-tune a pretrained ViT.
For fair comparison, I keep all the hyper-parameter the same: batch-size, optimizer...
But the result is not what I expected:
enter image description here
the above image is the GPU consumption of "linear-probing, lora, full-finetune" respectively.
It seems that lora only reduce a small portion of GPU memory compared to full-finetune
Here is my complete code:
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.utils.data import Subset
from torchvision.datasets import CIFAR100,Places365,Food101,StanfordCars,Flowers102
from torchvision.transforms import Compose, Resize, ToTensor, Normalize
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
import torch.optim as optim
from transformers import AutoImageProcessor, ViTModel,ViTForImageClassification
from peft import LoraConfig, get_peft_model
import wandb
import os
from tqdm import tqdm
import pickle
from util import setup_seed

os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "0"

#hyper-parameter
lr=2e-4
epochs=10
batch_size=256
dataset='flower102'
tune_mode='lora'
seed=42

#set random seed
setup_seed(seed)

if dataset=='place365_sub':
    num_class=10
elif dataset=='cifar100':
    num_class=100
elif dataset=='food101':
    num_class=101
elif dataset=='standfordcars':
    num_class=196
    epochs=30
elif dataset=='flower102':
    num_class=102

# Initialize wandb
wandb.init(project="vit-%s"%(dataset),name=tune_mode)
wandb.config.learning_rate = lr
wandb.config.batch_size = batch_size
wandb.config.epochs = epochs
wandb.config.dataset=dataset
wandb.config.mode=tune_mode
wandb.config.seed=42


class VIT4classification(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_classes):
        super(VIT4classification, self).__init__()
        self.vit = ViTModel.from_pretrained("google/vit-base-patch16-224-in21k")
        for param in self.vit.parameters():
            param.requires_grad = False

        self.classifier=nn.Linear(self.vit.config.hidden_size,num_classes)
        
    
    def forward(self, x):
        vit_output=self.vit(x).pooler_output
        logits=self.classifier(vit_output)

        return logits

if tune_mode=='linear_probing':
    model=VIT4classification(num_class)
elif tune_mode=='full-finetune':
    model=ViTForImageClassification.from_pretrained("google/vit-base-patch16-224-in21k",num_labels=num_class)
elif tune_mode=='lora':
    model=ViTForImageClassification.from_pretrained("google/vit-base-patch16-224-in21k",num_labels=num_class)
    config = LoraConfig(
    r=16,
    lora_alpha=16,
    target_modules=["query", "value"],
    lora_dropout=0.1,
    bias="none",
    modules_to_save=["classifier"],
    )
    model = get_peft_model(model, config)
    model.print_trainable_parameters()

if dataset=='cifar100':
    # Prepare the CIFAR100 dataset
    transform = Compose([
        Resize((224, 224)),
        ToTensor(),
        Normalize(mean=[0.5, 0.5, 0.5], std=[0.5, 0.5, 0.5])
    ])
    train_dataset = CIFAR100(root='../../../scr1/yuanfanp/cifar100', train=True, download=True, transform=transform)
    test_dataset = CIFAR100(root='../../../scr1/yuanfanp/cifar100', train=False, download=True, transform=transform)
    train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
    test_loader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False)

elif dataset=='place365_sub':
    transform = Compose([
        Resize((224, 224)),
        ToTensor(),
        Normalize(mean=[0.5, 0.5, 0.5], std=[0.5, 0.5, 0.5])
    ])

    # 加载完整的Places365数据集
    train_dataset = Places365('../../../scr1/yuanfanp/Places365',split='train-standard',small=True,download=False,transform=transform)
    test_dataset =Places365('../../../scr1/yuanfanp/Places365',split='val',small=True,download=False,transform=transform)

    # 选择用于训练和测试的类别
    selected_classes = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]  # 例如，选择前10个类别


    # 创建子集
    subset_indices_train = []
    subset_indices_test = []

    if not os.path.exists('../../../scr1/yuanfanp/Places365/train_sub.pkl'):
        print('=========prepare subset of places365(train)=========')
        for i, (img, label) in enumerate(tqdm(train_dataset)):
            if label in selected_classes:
                subset_indices_train.append(i)
        print('=========prepare subset of places365(val)=========')
        for i, (img, label) in enumerate(tqdm(test_dataset)):
            if label in selected_classes:
                subset_indices_test.append(i)
        with open('../../../scr1/yuanfanp/Places365/train_sub.pkl', 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(subset_indices_train, f)
        with open('../../../scr1/yuanfanp/Places365/test_sub.pkl', 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(subset_indices_test, f)
    else:
        with open('../../../scr1/yuanfanp/Places365/train_sub.pkl', 'rb') as f:
            subset_indices_train = pickle.load(f)
        with open('../../../scr1/yuanfanp/Places365/test_sub.pkl', 'rb') as f:
            subset_indices_test = pickle.load(f)
    

    print('=========num of places365(train):%d========='%(len(subset_indices_train)))
    print('=========num of places365(val):%d========='%(len(subset_indices_test)))

    # 创建子集数据集
    subset_train = Subset(train_dataset, subset_indices_train)
    subset_test = Subset(test_dataset, subset_indices_test)

    # 创建数据加载器
    train_loader = DataLoader(subset_train, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
    test_loader = DataLoader(subset_test, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False)

elif dataset=='food101':
    # Prepare the food101 dataset
    transform = Compose([
        Resize((224, 224)),
        ToTensor(),
        Normalize(mean=[0.5, 0.5, 0.5], std=[0.5, 0.5, 0.5])
    ])
    train_dataset = Food101(root='../../../scr1/yuanfanp/food101', split='train', download=True, transform=transform)
    test_dataset = Food101(root='../../../scr1/yuanfanp/food101', split='test', download=True, transform=transform)
    train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
    test_loader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False)

elif dataset=='standfordcars':
    # Prepare the standfordcar dataset
    transform = Compose([
        Resize((224, 224)),
        ToTensor(),
        Normalize(mean=[0.5, 0.5, 0.5], std=[0.5, 0.5, 0.5])
    ])
    train_dataset = StanfordCars(root='../../../scr1/yuanfanp', split='train', download=True, transform=transform)
    test_dataset = StanfordCars(root='../../../scr1/yuanfanp', split='test', download=True, transform=transform)
    train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
    test_loader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False)

elif dataset=='flower102':
    # Prepare the flower102 dataset
    transform = Compose([
        Resize((224, 224)),
        ToTensor(),
        Normalize(mean=[0.5, 0.5, 0.5], std=[0.5, 0.5, 0.5])
    ])
    train_dataset = Flowers102(root='../../../scr1/yuanfanp/flower102', split='train', download=True, transform=transform)
    test_dataset = Flowers102(root='../../../scr1/yuanfanp/flower102', split='test', download=True, transform=transform)
    train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
    test_loader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False)
    
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
model.to(device)

# 定义损失函数和优化器
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
if tune_mode=='linear_probing':
    optimizer = optim.Adam(model.classifier.parameters(), lr=lr)
elif tune_mode=='full-finetune':
    optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=lr)
elif tune_mode=='lora':
    optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=lr)

# 训练模型
num_epochs = 10
best_accuracy = 0.0

for epoch in range(epochs):
    model.train()
    running_loss = 0.0
    correct = 0
    total = 0

    print('============epoch %d============'%(epoch))

    for inputs, labels in tqdm(train_loader):
        inputs, labels = inputs.to(device), labels.to(device)

        optimizer.zero_grad()

        if tune_mode=='linear_probing':
            outputs = model(inputs)
        else:
            outputs=model(inputs).logits
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        running_loss += loss.item()
        _, predicted = outputs.max(1)
        total += labels.size(0)
        correct += predicted.eq(labels).sum().item()

    train_loss = running_loss / len(train_loader)
    train_accuracy = 100. * correct / total

    # 在测试集上评估模型
    model.eval()
    test_correct = 0
    test_total = 0

    with torch.no_grad():
        for inputs, labels in tqdm(test_loader):
            inputs, labels = inputs.to(device), labels.to(device)
            if tune_mode=='linear_probing':
                outputs = model(inputs)
            else:
                outputs=model(inputs).logits
            _, predicted = outputs.max(1)
            test_total += labels.size(0)
            test_correct += predicted.eq(labels).sum().item()

    test_accuracy = 100. * test_correct / test_total

    # 保存性能最好的模型
    if test_accuracy > best_accuracy:
        best_accuracy = test_accuracy
        if tune_mode=='linear_probing':
            os.makedirs('../../../scr1/yuanfanp/model/ViT/%s/%s/'%(dataset,tune_mode), exist_ok=True)
            torch.save(model.classifier.state_dict(), '../../../scr1/yuanfanp/model/ViT/%s/%s/best.pth'%(dataset,tune_mode))
        elif tune_mode=='full-finetune':
            os.makedirs('../../../scr1/yuanfanp/model/ViT/%s/%s/'%(dataset,tune_mode), exist_ok=True)
            torch.save(model.state_dict(), '../../../scr1/yuanfanp/model/ViT/%s/%s/best.pth'%(dataset,tune_mode))
        elif tune_mode=='lora':
            os.makedirs('../../../scr1/yuanfanp/model/ViT/%s/%s/'%(dataset,tune_mode), exist_ok=True)
            model.save_pretrained('../../../scr1/yuanfanp/model/ViT/%s/%s/best.pth'%(dataset,tune_mode))

    wandb.log({"Train Loss": train_loss, "Train Accuracy": train_accuracy,"test_accuracy":test_accuracy,"best_accuracy":best_accuracy})


Double check to make sure the model parameters have requires_grad=False. You set this explicitly for your VIT4classification model but not the other models. Also check what parameters you are passing to the optimizer to make sure it's only the lora modules. if that looks good, you can reduce the rank of the lora adapters

Thanks for your help. I carefully check the Peft code of huggingface. I found that, when we wrap a pre-trained model with 'get_peft_model(model, config)' to get a lora peft model, it will set the base-model's parameter freezed(requires_grad=False) and activate other modules' gradient (the classifier and lora module). Then I pass the whole model's parameter to optimizer, I guess it will only track the gradient of the parameters whose requires_grad property is set to True?@Karl
